# How to run a Node.js + Angular 4 project in production

Tags: node.js, angular, deployment

I have an application using Angular 4 and Node.js that I run in development mode with angular-cli and nodemon.

Obviously Angular runs on :4200 and Node.js runs on :3000, and I made a `proxy.config.json` to redirect `/api` requests to :3000 as below:

```
{
  "/api/*":{
    "target":"http://localhost:3000",
    "secure":false,
    "logLevel":"debug"
  }
}
```

I run the project using two scripts that I defined in my `package.json`:

```
"server": "nodemon server/server.js --watch server",
"dev": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"
```

Now I want to go through the production mode and deploy my application on a VPS. What is the best way to run this application on a VPS?

Comment: install node and pm2 on your vps. Use pm2 to run your application as daemon. Use apache or ngix to proxy all request to internal port your application is running on.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Node.js deployment

With an Apache server, you can use `Location` and `ReverseProxy` to expose your Node.js API:

/etc/apache2/site-availables/your-project.conf (on the `<VirtualHost:.80>` block, after `DocumentRoot` for example):

```
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>
  <Location /api>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:3000
  </Location>
```

And then you can use `pm2` to keep your Node.js application up in the background: *[How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)*

### 2. Angular deployment

For the Angular project, simply build it for a production environment: `ng build --prod (--aot)`

Transfer the generated files on your server, and point your VirtualHost on it.